# how do i define a php function with my code

Tags: php, string, function, output

i have this code
that count one string accorances i just cant explain my use but it really nice for me plese see here https://ideone.com/pvAIjW

code:

```
  <?php
   $te = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567891011121314151617181920';

  $text=strlen($te);
  if($text <=10)       
  { 
  $g == 2;
  }
  else
  {
   $x=$text;
  $y=2;
  $tempMod = (float)($x / $y);
  $tempMod = ($tempMod - (int)$tempMod)*$y;
  if($tempMod ==0)
  {
  $g = $x / $y;
  }
  else
  {
  $x = $x+1;
  $g = $x / $y;
  }
  }
  echo $g;
```

in my achievement i want it as a function so i just call 
       $output=function($string); 
       echo $output to get my result

big thanks in advance

Comment: Using functions is quite trivial in any language. If you are struggling with that, I advise to either buy a decent PHP book or follow good online tutorials. A good start is the PHP website: http://php.net/manual/en/langref.php

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Only you have to do is to send the $te variable like a parameter to the function:

```
function fnct($te){
     $text=strlen($te);
     if($text <=10)       
     { 
         $g == 2;
     }else{
         $x=$text;
         $y=2;
         $tempMod = (float)($x / $y);
         $tempMod = ($tempMod - (int)$tempMod)*$y;
         if($tempMod ==0)
         {
             $g = $x / $y;
         }else{
            $x = $x+1;
            $g = $x / $y;
         }
     }
     return $g;
}
```

And when you want to call this function you will use this code:

```
$te = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567891011121314151617181920';
$output = fnct($te);
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 2):

That would be like this. Just change all the instance of `$te` *(although you can still use `$te` if you want, I just changed it to avoid confusion)* with the parameter name *(which is $string)*, then instead of echoing `$g`, return it:

```
function functionName($string){
    $text=strlen($string);
    if($text <=10)       
    { 
        $g == 2;
    }
    else
    {
        $x=$text;
        $y=2;
        $tempMod = (float)($x / $y);
        $tempMod = ($tempMod - (int)$tempMod)*$y;
        if($tempMod ==0)
        {
            $g = $x / $y;
        }
        else
        {
            $x = $x+1;
            $g = $x / $y;
        }
     }
     return $g;
}
$te = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567891011121314151617181920';
$varName = functionName($te);
```

***NOTE***: Not to be rude, but this kind of problem can be easily searched, so I suggest you try reading documentations pertaining to PHP or find online tutorials, most of the time they cover using and creating functions

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $te = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567891011121314151617181920';

function name($value){

    $text=strlen($value);
    if($text <=10){
        $value == 2;
    }
    else{
      $x=$text;
      $y=2;
      $tempMod = (float)($x / $y);
      $tempMod = ($tempMod - (int)$tempMod)*$y;
      if($tempMod ==0){
        $g = $x / $y;
      }else{
        $x = $x+1;
        $value = $x / $y;
      }
    }
      return $value;

}
echo name($te);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function functionName($string){
    if(strlen($string) <=10) $g == 2;
    else {
        $x=strlen($string);
        $y=2;
        if(!(((float)($x / $y) - (int)((float)($x / $y)))*$y ==0)) $x++;
        $g = $x / $y;
     }
     return $g;
}
$te = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567891011121314151617181920';
$varName = functionName($te);
var_dump($varName);
```

The code perhaps will be better shorter. Up to you.